# How to replace an exact string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We're on SQL Server 2012 SP2

I'm trying to get some address standardization in place by cleaning up the junk address data we receive from an outside source. I'm having an issue where the replace function is replacing parts of a string unexpectedly.

We have a function that makes the data proper case, then I'm using a lot of replace functions to "clean" our data.

I'm having issues with changing things back to uppercase.

Here's a sample

What I'm dealing with

```
101 Second Ave Se
```

Here's what's happening

```
101 SEcond Ave SE
```

Here's how I need it to look

```
101 Second Ave SE
```

I've tried adding in collation in the replace statement, adding a space before and after the string in the replace function, etc...

Examples of what I've tried (with and without the collation)

```
replace(dbo.propercase(address1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, ' Se' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, ' SE')

replace(dbo.propercase(address1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, ' Se ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, ' SE ')

replace(dbo.propercase(address1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'Se ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'SE ')

replace(dbo.propercase(address1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'Se' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'SE')
```

And it still wants to replace every Se it finds with SE.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is no pattern where Second and SE are not in the same pattern. Formatting strings with sql server is choosing the wrong tool for the job. Do this in the presentation layer with a proper regular expression.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this in sql is to parse the address into strings using a space as the delimiter. Then have a predefined list of replacements in a table or make words where the LEN <= 2 to UPPER or some such. But this still is not really a task for the database.

Comment: This problem is so difficult, that there are vendors doing this as a service. Including USPS. It is much easier to find a service that can standardize the addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with the patindex function. This method will allow you to replace even when there are more words after the offending string.

```
declare @string nvarchar(255) = N'101 Second Ave Se Unit 4'
declare @toFind nvarchar(255) = N'se'
declare @toReplace nvarchar(255) = N'SE'

IF PATINDEX(N'%[^Aa-Zz]'+@toFind+'[^Aa-Zz]%','.'+@string+'.') > 0
SET @string = left(@string,PATINDEX(N'%[^Aa-Zz]'+@toFind+'[^Aa-Zz]%','.'+@string+'.')-1)+@toReplace+right(@string,len(@string)-((PATINDEX(N'%[^Aa-Zz]'+@toFind+'[^Aa-Zz]%','.'+@string+'.')-1)+len(@toReplace)))

select @string
```

It's not going to be very efficient, but it works.

Comment: This one did the trick. SE doesn't just appear at the end of the string and this took care of the anomaly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
address1 = left(address1, len(address1)-3) + ‘ SE’ where right(address1,3) = ‘ se’
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your answer (using the tick to the left)

Comment: Unfortunately SE can appear anywhere in the string and this one only checks if it appears at the end. Thank you for your contribution though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a one-time manual clean up.  In absence of an elegant answer, you could do two replaces.

Go ahead and swap out `se` for `SE`

Then swap out `SEcond` for `Second` to correct it.

Comment: I wish it was a one time thing. There are more variations of this beside it replacing "Second", we also have a bunch of random words that contain "SE". I'm probably doing more than I need to for another department but I don't want to deal with this more than I need to :)